# ASP.NET 5 Identity 3 users get signed out after application restart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

We are using ASP.NET Identity 3.

Our users are randomly getting signed out automatically. To reproduce this issue, I tried application restart, all users signed out, even those who had checked `Remember me`.

It only happens in Production, works fine on development environment.

**Update:**

We have only one server in production.

Comment: I solved a similar issue by implementing SQL Server based session in IIS

Comment: This example works in ASP.NET Core 7: [ASP.Net Core Identity login status lost after deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563627/4049371)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to [configure data protection](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html) in the production server. I assume that in your local machine the website runs as a local user so the registry hives *can* be created and read. While if you run it as a user without a local profile (default IIS app pool user option), it may not have the permission/s to create or read the keys required. You'll need to run [this provisioning script](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/dev/Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1) in that case.

Have a good read about their guide on [Publishing to IIS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#publishing-to-iis). That step is [documented there](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#configure-data-protection).

Comment: Thanks! Provisioning script fixed my problem,

Answer (score 1):

The production machine might be using multiple servers. In that case, the server to which a user first connects might not be the same server to which that user later connects. In that case, if you are using session IDs, you must keep user sessions in sync across servers.