# ASP.NET MVC 6 custom user identity, persisting the logged-in user for a long time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

So I have ASP.NET MVC 6 + AngularJS application with custom user identity (not using EF) which authenticates the user against different db without EF, etc.

I have a couple of custom implementations of some interfaces needed for the user identity to work.

- `IUserStore<MyUser>`, `IUserPasswordStore<MyUser>` - only a couple of methods are implemented for getting the user with my custom code. Nothing interesting there.
- `IPasswordHasher<MyUser>` implementation for validating the hashed password using my own code for decrypting the password, etc.
- `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUser>` implementation for creating the `ClaimsPrincipal` object containing some custom claims for my own purposes.

In the `AccountControler` for signing in and logging off I am using this:

```
SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, shouldLockout: false)
SignInManager.SignOut();
```

where the SignInManager is my custom one - `SignInManager<MyUser>`.

So far everything is straight forward.

Now in the `Startup.cs` I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserStore<MyUser>, ApplicationUserStore>());
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserPasswordStore<MyUser>, ApplicationUserStore>());
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IPasswordHasher<MyUser>, ApplicationSitePasswordHasher>());
    services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyUser>, MyUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>());

    services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyUserRole>();

    services.ConfigureIdentity(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 1;

        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        options.User.UserNameValidationRegex = string.Empty;
    });

    services.ConfigureIdentityApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
        options.AuthenticationScheme = IdentityOptions.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        options.LoginPath = PathString.Empty; 
    });

    ...

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
{
     ...

     app.UseIdentity();

     ...

     app.UseMvc(routes => .... )
}
```

And I also have custom authorization attribute dealing when the user gets 401 in the angular http async call. The idea is something like that:

```
public class MyAuthorize : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        bool isAuth = bool isAuth = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        bool isFromClient = ...
        string loginPath = ...

        if (!isAuth && isFromClient)
        {
            ...
        }
        else if (!isAuth && !isFromClient)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginPath);
        }
        else
        {
            await next();
        }
    }
}
```

**The question** : Even though I have my cookie to expire after 30 days (in that case) I still get unauthenticated (The `context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property is `false`) after some period of time and get redirected to the login page due to my logic in the `MyAuthorize` attribute.

The idle time-out in the IIS pool is 0 as well.

How to make my custom user identity to persist the authenticated user for a really long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does "some period of time" is about "30 minutes since login"? :)

Implement `IUserSecurityStampStore<User>` interface.

Long description is in [ASP.NET 5 Identity 3 users get signed out after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162791/asp-net-5-identity-3-users-get-signed-out-after-some-time)