# Asp Net Core authentication troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

I have made asp net core web app with Angular. It is using authentication based on cookies using standard net core authentication mechanism. All is working fine until IIS restart (recycle). After application restarted all users becomes unauthenticated  and needs to relogin.

May be some one knows what should be done to make information stored in cookies be actual for several days and not depending on application restart.

This is the piece of code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<MyAppContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString));
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
  {
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
  })
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyAppContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  services.AddAuthorization();
  services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddCookie(options =>
       {
          options.SlidingExpiration = true;
          options.ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
          options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Login";
          options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Logout";
          options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
       });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

Comment: Not remember exactly for .net core, but you need to keep your encryption key in your application config file.

Comment: I thought about it, .Net core don't uses config file from IIS.

Comment: yes but you can use that in appSetting.json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asp.Net Core uses the `Data Protection` mechanism to generate temporary `encryption keys`. and with the restart of the server or `IIS`, these keys are lost and `re-generated`.

In order that the keys for encrypting web application information are stored permanently and not lost with the server restart you can go to `Application pool` setting in `IIS` and set `Load user profile` to `True`

[image]

In this case, the keys will be permanently stored in the user's profile folder for the application's `application pool`, encrypted by the Windows `DPAPI` mechanism.

Or you can check these links [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563627/7086678),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49606724/7086678) to keep the login status after `iis` reset

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tested this chages, but it have not help :-( After IIS restart still need to login once more

Comment: @antonad i updated my answer. i hope helpful for you

Comment: Thanks, this works. Very simple solution, but I missed it.

Comment: @antonad Good luck ;)